# How to integrate Chart.js into Salesforce?

Tags: charts, chart.js, salesforce, lwc

I'm looking to visualize some data in Salesforce using Chart.js.

I downloaded it using npm and retrieved the **chart.js** file from there. I then tried adding this file as a static resource in Salesforce, but it's not working as expected. How can I properly integrate and utilize Chart.js within Salesforce? Are there any steps I might be missing, or any best practices I should be aware of? Any guidance would be appreciated.